# what function does OWIN exactly use to generate a token; Can it be leveraged?

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, token, owin

I can see the way to generate tokens using the following code
 as outlined in

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
};

// Token Generation
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);

var bearerAuth = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
};

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(bearerAuth);


public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{


    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        var manager = new UserManager<User, long>(new UserStore(new UserRepository()));
        var user = await manager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
        }
        else
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("name",user.Email));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }


    }
}
```

As a consumer I make a REST call to http://localhost:9000/token with my credentials and `magically` get an access token

I would like to be able to leverage that token generation function for use in other scenarios to manually create a token that would be valid for `**this particular**` OWIN server.

Secondly, is it possible to have multiple authorization providers that can be conditionally used by this server. If so how does one do that without implementing a token generator from scratch (like the external login stuff)?

Answer (score 3):

For what it worth, here is how we do it:

```
        var options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions();
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(...);

        var tokenContext = new AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(null, options.AccessTokenFormat, ticket);
        await context.options.AccessTokenProvider.CreateAsync(tokenContext);
        var token = tokenContext.Token;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) token = tokenContext.SerializeTicket();
        return token;
```

options must be your OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions from your app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options) call.

This mostly replicate how OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler generate a Bearer token.
[AspNetKatana/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs)

Answer (score 1):

You can [see the code here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/tree/9f6e09af6bf203744feb5347121fe25f6eec06d8/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth).  It can be hard to follow. There is a lot that goes into making it follow the OAuth spec and be pluggable (you can swap out the token format for example) but ultimately the default configuration is doing something like this behind the scenes to generate tokens:

```
   var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity("bob")), new AuthenticationProperties());
   IDataProtector dataProtecter = null;
   var format = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtecter);
   var accessToken = format.Protect(ticket);
```

*Usually* you should not customize it to much or generate out-of-band tokens unless you understand the security implications and are sure the out-of-the-box code isn't sufficient.  Consider something like Identity Server if the built in stuff doesn't do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The OWIN guide http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server
has the following method to generate tokens.....

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _authenticationCodes =
     new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.Ordinal);

 private void CreateAuthenticationCode(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
 {
     context.SetToken(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"));
     _authenticationCodes[context.Token] = context.SerializeTicket();
 }

 private void ReceiveAuthenticationCode(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
 {
     string value;
     if (_authenticationCodes.TryRemove(context.Token, out value))
     {
         context.DeserializeTicket(value);
     }
 }
```

This is one way but I still don't know if this is the official way that MS implements it. It would be nice to know if there's a built-in function that can do this.

Comment: A note: GUID is **NOT** cryptographically secure

Comment: thank you, i was hesitating on using this even though its on MS official guides. Would you know of any better ways ?

Comment: Note this code is _not_ generating an access token on "SetToken".  It is generating a code for use with OAuth authorization code grant type. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1